# How do I write this sql query in order to pull in the lead.converteddate respective to the event the member attended?

Tags: postgresql, salesforce

I have two different events with two different dates and a handful of members to each event.

```
Campaign Name (Event)     Start Date
A                          6/25/2019
B                          10/2/2019
```

Member 1 went to Event A on 6/25/2019 and later converted to a closed/won deal on 9/1/2019.

Member 2 went to Event B on 10/2/2019 but had already converted to a closed/won deal on 6/31/2019.

I want to write a query that selects members of Event A that converted to a closed deal after the event (convert_date > 6/25/2019) while also selecting members of Event B that converted to a closed deal after Event B (convert_date > 10/2/2019).

I could write the query

```
SELECT 
     lead.id, 
     lead.converteddate, 
     lead.event_campaign_name, 
     campaign.startdate
     campaign.name


FROM salesforce.lead
LEFT JOIN salesforce.campaign ON lead.id = campaign.leadid

WHERE lead.converteddate > '6/25/2019'

AND lead.event_campaign_name IN ('A','B')
```

This will correctly capture people who went to event A then converted after attending event A. The problem is this will also capture members of event B who converted before going to event B.

How do I write this query in order to pull in the lead.converteddate respective to the event the member attended?  Excluding those members that converted before attending the respective event

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your where clause to accept both cases individually.  Something like:

```
WHERE ((lead.converteddate > '6/25/2019' AND lead.event_campaign_name = 'A')
    OR (lead.converteddate > '10/2/2019 ' AND lead.event_campaign_name = 'B'))
```

The above solution is only applicable to campaign events A & B.  If you want something universal use:

```
WHERE lead.converteddate > lead.event_date
```

This assumes you have a field that is the event date.  I assume you don't have an event date column, because that would make the problem somewhat trivial.

Comment: "This assumes you have a field that is the event date. I assume you don't have an event date column, because that would make the problem somewhat trivial."  This is what I needed. Seems obvious in hindsight - my brain must not be working :P